# Mysql search query - include column from joined table

Tags: mysql, join

If I do a search query in the current table, there is no problem:

```
SELECT * FROM articles 
WHERE CONCAT(title, content, author) LIKE '%searchstring%'
```

But if I want to include a column from a joined table, I can't add that column to the where clause:

```
    SELECT articles.*, associations.name AS association_name 
FROM articles 
    JOIN associations 
    ON articles.association_id = associations.id
    WHERE CONCAT(title, content, author,association_name ) 
LIKE '%searchstring%'
```

the error becomes `"Unknown column 'association_name' in where clause"`

So how would I include that column in the search query?

Comment: associations.name would do. Also, it's likely that you would want CONCAT_WS in this instance - but see The Impaler's comment below. For further help, see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Use `associations.name` in `CONCAT`

Comment: That query will be really slow, since there's no way you can use an index on it. Just saying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to do the write up of the answers provided above in the comments. You should do:

```
SELECT articles.*, associations.name AS association_name 
FROM articles 
JOIN associations ON articles.association_id = associations.id
WHERE CONCAT(title, content, author, associations.name) 
  LIKE '%searchstring%'
```

Comment: I accepted your solution but actually "associations.name" from the above comment is what worked - if you could update your where clause to that :).. I thought I had tried this, but apparently not.

Comment: @Galivan Fixed as requested.